# How do I add a variable to the end of a link?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an id variable (in this case, demo) to the end of the link but I can't make it work, how can I do it?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', 'https://discordapp.com/api/users/412315079598407691', true)
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bot bot-token")
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.avatar;
    }
  };
request.send()

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    x.setAttribute("src", `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/412315079598407691/`+ demo);
    x.setAttribute("width", "350");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
  }
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? You haven't defined `demo` anywhere in that snippet

Comment: Since you're using a template literal, you can use `${demo}` inside the literal instead of concatenation.

Comment: i've added the code snippet calling the demo there

Comment: You added a code snippet but again, no where in the above do you actually define demo.  Are you saying that demo = innerHtml of the element demo? Those are two different things.

Comment: (*There was an overlap with basic's comment above*) There seems to be a DOM object with the ID `demo` (at least your JS code relies on this), but nothing like `var demo = foo` is happening anywhere.

Comment: @Pida [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278) - an element with `id="demo"` actually creates a `window.demo` property. So, it exists as a global variable.

Comment: @VLAZ Wow, I've never heard of this! However, I don't think it's a good idea to rely on this. Even a dash in the id attribute breaks this functionality. @tmarshguy You didn't mention what exactly is not working yet. "foo" + demo might give you something like `foo[object HTMLDivElement]`, is this what's happening?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of
``https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/412315079598407691/`+ demo`

try doing
`https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/412315079598407691/${demo}`
Please make sure that `demo.toString()` returns what you want. As things can get weird when you stringify an object.